# Update Image attributes in wordpress Gutenberg with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to update class attribute of a figure image block in wordpress Gutenberg.
When I modify block attributes, changes are not taken into account

```
wp.data
    .dispatch("core/block-editor")
    .updateBlockAttributes(curblock.clientId, curblock.attributes);
  wp.data
    .dispatch("core/block-editor")
    .updateBlock(curblock.clientId, curblock.attributes);
```

This piece of code is working well with text block but not with the image, anyone knows how to perform update of the block and save it?

Thank you

Comment: Did you consider that the changes to the blocks you are making, will only work after the blocks are re-saved or newly created? To my knowledge, existing blocks will not get any changes undless manually processed.